# How do I make different things happen at different times in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an alternative [agc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer) in python3, but i can't figure out how to make multiple things happen at different times (for example, thing A happens after 1 second and thing B happens after 2 seconds) the code I tried looks like this

```
if start_time < 9.9:
        print("Timer will wait for sometime before calling the function")
    else:
        print("Pitch and roll maneuver started.")
    if start_time < 23.325:
        print("Timer will wait for sometime before calling the function")
    else:
        print("Roll maneuver ended.")
    if start_time < 101.34:
        print("Timer will wait for sometime before calling the function")
    else:
        print("S-IC center engine cutoff command.")
    if end_time - start_time < 120.0:
        print("Timer will wait for sometime before calling the function") 
    else:
        print("Pitch maneuver ended.")
```

I took into consideration trying to make it so after 1 second thing A happens and thing A also sets a another timer for thing B to happen, but that would be a lot of `def`'s and I dont want to make the file so big that my computer crashes

Comment: I'm using python3

Comment: Have you looked at [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) in the standard library?  It sounds like that's what you're looking for, but if not you may want to provide more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user1234 I looked into it, my goal is for thingA and thingB to do different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `while` loop and `sleep`

```py
from time import sleep

start_time = 0
end_time = 11

while True:
    start_time += 1
    if start_time == 3:
        print("\nPitch and roll maneuver started.")
    elif start_time == 6:
        print("\nRoll maneuver ended.")
    elif start_time == 9:
        print("\nS-IC center engine cutoff command.")
    elif  start_time == end_time:
        print("\nPitch maneuver ended.")
        break
    else:
        print("Timer will wait for sometime before calling the function", end="\r")
    
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, but just so i can get a better understanding of it, why do I add the \n att the beggining?

Comment: also how do i make it work with decimals